# twilio nodejs callback function (action) for gather

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I dont know how i can do this code in nodejs :

```
  <?php
    // page located at http://example.com/process_gather.php
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    echo "<Response><Say>You entered " . $_REQUEST['Digits'] . "</Say></Response>";
        ?>
```

this is tutorial 
i make the frist function in nodejs but for /process_gather.php i dont know how we can wirte (echo say ) in nodejs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/complex_gather.xml -->
<Response>
    <Gather action="/process_gather.php" method="GET">
        <Say>
            Please enter your account number,
            followed by the pound sign
        </Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>




  <?php
    // page located at http://example.com/process_gather.php
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    echo "<Response><Say>You entered " . $_REQUEST['Digits'] . "</Say></Response>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out the [TwiML Basics](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/#twimlBasic) section of the Twilio Node helper library.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer
i have also other  Twilio  question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509793/twilio-lambda-backend-aws)